# Python telegram bot delete reply message

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I want to delete a message sent to the telegram group by a bot. When users respond to that message, the message should be deleted. I tried to do it the following way.

```
def reply(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):                                        
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    context.bot.delete_message(chat_id=user_id, 
    message_id=update.message.reply_to_message.message_id)
```

But the following error occurred: `telegram.error.BadRequest: Message to delete not found`

Comment: Is the privacy mode enabled for your bot? If so, then my guess would be that your bot doesn't know about the `reply_to_message`. Try disabling the privacy mode.